# Struts 1.3: request attributes lost after submit

Tags: forms, validation, httprequest, struts-1

I have two jsp page, say `form.jsp` and `myForm.jsp`.

In the first page, form.jsp, there is a radio button group (the form name is "form").

When the user submits this form, some info are retrieved from a db and with these informations the form in myForm.jsp is built (the form name is "myForm").

The problem is that when this second form is submitted, only the errors are displayed but not the form fields created from db values.
For example, I retrieve from database labels and values for two radio buttons (property="prop").

In `struts-config.xml`, I have:

```
<form-bean name="myForm" type="org.apache.struts.validator.MyValidatorActionForm">
<form-property name="prop" type="java.lang.Integer"></form-property>
</form-bean>

<action path="/form" input="/jsp/home.jsp" name="form" scope="request" type="myPackage.LoadInfo">

<forward name="Success" path="/jsp/myForm.jsp"/>  
<forward name="Failure" path="/jsp/home.jsp" />     
</action>

 <action path="/myForm" input="/jsp/myForm.jsp" name="myForm" validate="true" scope="request" type="myPackage.MyValidatorAction"> 
<forward name="Success" path="/jsp/success.jsp"/>  
<forward name="Failure" path="/jsp/failure.jsp"/>
</action>
```

In `myForm.jsp`:

```
<html:form action="/myForm">
 <div><label>*&nbsp;<bean:message key="myForm.label"/></label>
<c:forEach var="propTypes" items="${props}">
<html:radio property="prop" value="${propTypes.value}">${propTypes.label}
     </html:radio>
     </c:forEach>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<html:errors property="prop" />
 </div>
<div><html:submit><bean:message key="myForm.label2"/></html:submit></div>
 </html:form>
```

In `validation.xml`:

After the form submit without select any radio button, the error is displayed, but not the radio buttons.

How could I maintain all the request attributes?
I tried to use scope session too, but nothing has changed:

```
 <action path="/myForm" input="/jsp/myForm.jsp" name="myForm" validate="true" scope="session" type="myPackage.MyValidatorAction"> 
<forward name="Success" path="/jsp/success.jsp"/>  
<forward name="Failure" path="/jsp/failure.jsp"/>
</action>
```

I resolved by using:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("props", props);
```

in the Action `LoadInfo` called before the display of the form.

In `myForm.jsp` I use:

```
 request.getSession().getAttribute("props");
```

Instead in the struts-config.xml, the scope remains request.

Nevertheless, this isn't a good solution, 'cause different browser tabs share the same session.

How could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Your form fields in your jsp page should have corresponding properties in your ActionForm class.

So if your jsp has a the following radio button

```
<html:radio name="myForm" property="name">
```

You need a corresponding property in your action form as follows and make sure you have the getters and setters:

```
public class MyClass{
private String name; 
public String getName()
{ 
   return name; 
}
public void setName(String name){
   this.name = name; 
}
```

If you set it up this way, the user entered values should still be there when your page refreshes.

Comment: I have it, with the private int prop, and the get and set methods. The issue is that when there is an error (in this case any radio button is selected), the error is displayed, but not the radio buttons. There is only the label and the msg error.

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good idea or whether it will work or not but have you tried changing the scope from request to session?

Comment: I thought so too and I've already tried to change it to session, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try this: In your action class do a SysOut on the radio button property when the error happens and see what gets printed out. This way you know if the object exists anymore when the error occurs.

Comment: if I don't select the button and then I submit the form, the validation via xml is done (the error msg is printed), but the execute method of the Action class MyValidatorAction is not called (I have no exception, nothing). Instead, if I select a radio button and then submit the form the execute method is called, the value of radio property is well printed on System.out, but the printing of the "props" object gives a null pointer exception (System.out.println(request.getAttribute("props").toString());)